# CSS transition dropdown menu on hover - absolute positioning left (_s wordpress theme)

Tags: css, wordpress, sass

I have a drop down menu that I would like to transition using css.

The drop down is displayed on hover using absolute positioning `left:-999em` and `left:100%` and I would like it to gently ease in and out on hover.

Amoungst other things I've tried the following

```
.main-navigation ul ul li:hover > ul {
    left: 100%;
    transition: left 0.5s ease;
}
```

I keep on leaving this issue and coming back to it and now I really have thrown in the towel and I'm asking for help. I'm clearly doing something silly.

**[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/stemie/0apf67a8/) of this example**

Im using _s theme from Wordpress and SASS.

```
.main-navigation {
    clear: both;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;

    ul {
        list-style: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding-left: 0;

        ul {
            box-shadow: 0 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
            float: left;
            position: absolute;
            top: 1.5em;
            left: -999em;
            z-index: 99999;

            ul {
                left: -999em;
                top: 0;
            }

            li {
                &:hover > ul {
                    left: 100%;
                }
            }

            a {
                width: 200px;
                }

                :hover > a {
                }

            a:hover {
            }
        }

        li:hover > ul {
            left: auto;
        }
    }
    li {
        float: left;
        position: relative;

        &:hover > a {
        }
    }
    a {
        display: block;
        text-decoration: none;
    }

    .current_page_item a,
    .current-menu-item a {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your SASS is quiet complex and nested quite a lot so it looks like you've missed a level out somewhere.

Using CSS (converted the SASS via SASSMeister) it was possible to see that the hover effect had not been applied to the first level `li`.

Also, 999em is a **lot**, you might want to consider reducing that or speeding up the transtion.

**Reduced CSS** using available classes.

```
.main-navigation {
  clear: both;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
}
.main-navigation ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
}
.sub-menu { 
  box-shadow: 0 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  float: left;
  position: absolute;
  top: 1.5em;
  left: -999em;
  z-index: 99999;
  transition: left .25s ease;   
}

.main-navigation ul li:hover > .sub-menu {
  left:0;
}

.main-navigation ul ul a {
  width: 200px;
  padding: 1em;
}

.main-navigation li {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}
.main-navigation a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-right: 1em;
}
```

[**JSfiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/0apf67a8/3/)